# Refreshing / Cycling through a parsed RSS feed every 5 mins

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, rss

I am working on a monitor signage display and have a "welcome to RSS" feed with just a title and desc. I have code from feedEk that's been tweaked a bit to parse the feed and cycle it so I only have one title and desc. showing at a time. This feed could be added to or deleted info at any time so I need it to refresh every five mins. I've tried several solutions on here and just can't seem to work it out.

Here is the adjusted FeedEk code with comments on the adjustments:

```
(function (e) {
e.fn.FeedEk = function (t) {
var n = {
    FeedUrl: "http://myrss.com/",
    MaxCount: 1,
    ShowDesc: true,
    ShowPubDate: false,
    CharacterLimit: 100,
    TitleLinkTarget: "_self",
    iterate: false
};
if (t) {
    e.extend(n, t)
}
var r = e(this).attr("id");
var i;

processFeedData = function (t) {
    //This just makes it flash too much
    //e("#" + r).empty();
    var s = "";
    en = t.responseData.feed.entries;

    if (n.iterate == true) {
        //Setting a variable to store current item
        i = window.feedcur = typeof(window.feedcur) === 'undefined' ? 0 : window.feedcur;

        t = en[i];
        s = makeString(t);

        //incrementing the current for the next time we loop through
        window.feedcur = ((i+1)%en.length);
    } else {
        for (i=0;i<en.length;i++) {
            t = en[i];
            s += makeString(t);
        }
    }
    //Changing this to just replace what was there (less blinky feeling)
    e("#" + r).html('<ul class="feedEkListSm">' + s + "</ul>");
}

makeString = function (t) {
    s = '<li><div class="itemTitleSm"><a href="' + t.link + '" target="' + n.TitleLinkTarget + '" >' + t.title + "</a></div><br>";
    if (n.ShowPubDate) {
        i = new Date(t.publishedDate);
        s += '<div class="itemDateSm">' + i.toLocaleDateString() + "</div>"
    }
    if (n.ShowDesc) {
        if (n.DescCharacterLimit > 0 && t.content.length > n.DescCharacterLimit) {
            s += '<div class="itemContentSm">' + t.content.substr(0, n.DescCharacterLimit) + "...</div>"
        } else {
            s += '<div class="itemContentSm">' + t.content + "</div>"
        }
    }
    return s;
}

if (typeof(window.feedContent) === 'undefined') {
    e("#" + r).empty().append('<div style="padding:3px;"><img src="loader.gif" /></div>');
    e.ajax({
        url: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=" + n.MaxCount + "&output=json&q=" + encodeURIComponent(n.FeedUrl) + "&hl=en&callback=?",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (t) {
            window.feedContent = t;
            processFeedData(window.feedContent);
        }
    });
} else {
    processFeedData(window.feedContent);
}        

}
})(jQuery)
```

On the php page I have the following code which cycles through on an interval. I've tried wrapping this into another function that refreshes it but that didn't work. I've also tried just refreshing the page, but that just makes the whole page blink and still doesn't refresh the feed. It seems to refresh every 12 to 24 hours.

```
<!-- this is for the rss feed -->
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function () {
feedsettings = {
    FeedUrl: 'http://myrss.com/',
    MaxCount: 100,
    ShowDesc: true,
    ShowPubDate: false,
    DescCharacterLimit: 100,
    iterate: true
}
$('#divRss').FeedEk(feedsettings);

setInterval(function(){
    $('#divRss').FeedEk(feedsettings);
},7000);
});

</script>

<style>
.rssDiv{float:right; padding-left:35px;}
ul{width:500px !important}
</style>
<!-- end feed stuffs -->
```

Any help guidance assistance or direction is immensely appreciated. I have to make this self sustaining with little to no extra installations. I've also posted this on code review but I think that may have been the wrong place to post this initially.